# Bootstrap general button to toggle accordions

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm new on jQuery and try to setup a general expand/collapse button for the twitter bootstrap accordion plugin.
In my code I've an array div's ids I want to expand/collaspe, and the loop I use works well to do that.

But if I expand/collaspe manually accordions by clicking accordion-heading link the concerned divs don't expand or collapse anymore, even if the "in" class is well added.

Here is my loop :

```
for(i=0;i<selectedRows.length;i++){
    if($("#"+a).find("div#collapse_"+selectedRows[i]+'.in').length==1)
        $("#"+a).find("div#collapse_"+selectedRows[i]).removeClass("in");
    else
        $("#"+a).find("div#collapse_"+selectedRows[i]).addClass("in");
}
```

Can you see what's wrong ?

Thanks a lot.

Edit : to complete here is the code for an accordion

```
<div id="accordion_4" class="accordion">
<div class="accordion-group">
    <divclass="accordion-heading">
        <a href="#collapse_4" data-parent="#accordion_4" data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle">
    Details</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="collapse_4">
        <div class="accordion-inner">
            Collapsible group
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code for the global button :

```
<i onclick="toggleExpand('batchForm');" class="btn">Collaps/expand details</i>
```

For the toggleExpand function I send the id of the form I use to see which rows are checked (checkbox) to be able to expand or collapse them in a click.

Comment: Can you post some more of your code, particularly how you are attaching the click event to the link - if not after the DOM is ready then the event may not have bound to the accordion-heading link

Comment: I cant see anything wrong with this loop, maybe you post (like PassKit already said) more of your code. I also recommend you to use the `.toggleClass()` method.

Comment: Ok, so there is the code for my accordions :
where 4 is the id I've in an array...

`<div id="accordion_4" class="accordion">
 <div class="accordion-group">
  <divclass="accordion-heading">
   <a href="#collapse_4" data-parent="#accordion_4" data-toggle="collapse" style="display:inline; padding:0;" class="accordion-toggle">
  Details</a>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-body collapse in" id="collapse_4">
   <div class="accordion-inner">
    Collapsible group
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more simple answer - just add...

```
            $(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', 'button[data-toggle=collapse]', expand);
```

to your bootstrap.js around line 636 under COLLAPSE DATA-API section.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off not modifying any class of the accordion, and interacting with it by triggering `click` on the appropriate heading:

Example :

```
var $accordLinks=$('.accordion .accordion-toggle');

$('.btn').click(function(){
   $accordLinks.eq( $(this).index()).click()
})
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/RB7cT/

Comment: Thanks
I'll try this tomorrow and will post the result.

Answer (score 0):

finally I use this function, which do the trick, a little bit slowly on 34 checkboxes but works. But if someone found something faster, I'm insterested.

```
    function toggleExpand(a){
        $("#"+a).find("input:checkbox:checked").each(function( index ) {
            $("#"+a+" .accordion .accordion-toggle").eq(index).click();
        });
    }
```